# Cant declare an array of classes outside Main in Java

Tags: java

I want to create an array of classes outside Main class, but it won't compile. If i put ObjectArray code into Main class everything works fine. I tried making a contructor, extend class, but nothing seems to work. Couldn't find the answer in google. How to make it work?

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ObjectArray dd = new ObjectArray();
        dd.toString();
    }
}
class ObjectArray {
        Account obj[] = new Account[2] ;
        obj[0] = new Account();  //Error: Invalid method declaration, return type required
        obj[1] = new Account();  
        obj[0].setData(1,2);
        obj[1].setData(3,4);

        public void toString() {
            obj[0].showData();
            obj[1].showData();
        }
}
class Account{
    int a,b;

    public void setData(int c,int d){
        a=c;
        b=d;
    }
    public void showData(){
        System.out.println("Value of a ="+a);
        System.out.println("Value of b ="+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to assign the values in a constructor of a method.

Comment: As @Jens The piece of code that assigns values needs to be within a method block...and in this case looks like one option would be a constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have code directly in a class. It needs to be in a method, constructor, or initializer block.

Here, you'd put the code in an initializer block:

```
class ObjectArray {
    Account[] obj = new Account[2];
    {
        obj[0] = new Account();
        obj[1] = new Account();
        obj[0].setData(1,2);
        obj[1].setData(3,4);
    }

    ...
}
```

I would however recommend creating a constructor to initialize the object, and then use an array initializer.

You also need to rename the `void toString()` method, since it clashes with the `String toString()` method inherited from `Object`.

In the following code I have also added various spaces to format according to standard style guidelines. Makes the code easier to read.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ObjectArray dd = new ObjectArray();
        dd.show();
    }
}
class ObjectArray {
    Account[] obj = { new Account(1, 2), new Account(3, 4) };

    public void show() {
        obj[0].showData();
        obj[1].showData();
    }
}
class Account {
    private int a, b;

    public Account() {
    }
    public Account(int c, int d) {
        a = c;
        b = d;
    }
    public void setData(int c, int d) {
        a = c;
        b = d;
    }
    public void showData() {
        System.out.println("Value of a = " + a);
        System.out.println("Value of b = " + b);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Value of a = 1
Value of b = 2
Value of a = 3
Value of b = 4
```